# Can I change Lightroom keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10?

Tags: lightroom, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have changed my keyboard to a 60%, wireless mechanical and the '\' key has been moved and now requires a combination of keys to be held (ctrl + alt + #).

This obviously impacts my ability to switch between before and after previews.

I am wondering if I can change the keyboard preset shortcuts to a different key so that I can more easily switch between the two?

I am running **Windows 10**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was forwarded to this link from another site that appears to have some form of an answer: https://www.lightroomqueen.com/custom-keyboard-shortcuts/

**TL;DR**

- Navigate to: `Windows—C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Lightroom\Resources\en\`
- Create a plain text file in that folder and name it TranslatedStrings_Lr_en_US.txt
- Search another language's file for the shortcut you wish to copy, ie `Resources\es\TranslatedStrings_Lr_es_ES.txt`
- Use search function to find specific shortcut required and copy into the new .txt file (ie. `“$$$/LibraryMenus/MenuShortcut/DecreaseRating=a”`)
- Save the file and open up Lightroom

Comment: @flolilolilo - The article is kind of... verbose. I thought leaving a link would be best, but I can copy and paste for you if you like.

Comment: My apologies for reviving this thread but it appears that this trick is no longer working. Lightroom recently received an update (which added the Texture slider) which broke this workaround. I noticed that the folder "en" was removed and re-adding it causes Lightroom to not start. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @Tomas- Hi!. Nope, I can not confirm this... I just added the folder with the text document and Lighroom started just fine. I used it to change the shortcuts for the brush size to , and . in a German keyboard. It worked just as it used to on the older version. So your problem must be somehting else. Just wanted to let you know. PS At first I could not directly add the txt file to the location, so I had to create it somewhere else and move it there with administrator rights.

Comment: Worked for me in May 2022 using Windows 11 and LRC 11.3.1